# Conditional Selection on Julia DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julia

Suppose I had a Dataframe `df` in `Pandas` with columns `ColA`, `ColB`, `ColC`,.... with rows `Row1`, `Row2`, `Row3`,...
If I want to acccess a part of `df` based on the values of a certain column (say A) I can do so as follows:

```
df
df[df['ColA'] == value]
```

This returns a `Series`. Now, I can even used some of the built in methods on this `Series` such as `df[df['ColA'] == value].sum()` or `df[df['ColA'] == value].mean()`.

Is there a similar method to do the same thing with `DataFrames.jl` on Julia?

Comment: I have voted to close the question as exactly the same question was asked just a few days ago and it has many alternative answers listed there.